# zoom panel in and out with its content VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, zooming, panel, mousewheel

using windows forms-visual basic 2013, I designed form with 2 panels left panel contain some buttons and right panel act as a drawing area for user.

user can add some labels, drag and drop them any location on panel and 
when user drag label out of panel bounders (right or down) scroll bar shown.

Now

I need to add feature to use mouse wheel to zoom in and out this panel only  with its content.

or just use button to zoom this panel to fit on screen (form) and reset it to original size

I tried some docking and dock styles but it not working as it should and I don't need to use table panel (user can arrange labels in any location on panel)

[image]

Comment: You need to recalculate the *positions* and *sizes* of all the controls in panel depending on the zoom factor.

Comment: You need to build a Container (a Class object) for all the drawn objects on that `Panel`. This Container references all the objects and their properties, among which, of course, `Location` and `Size`. When a `MouseWhell` event is raised, re-calculate the relative position and dimension of all the Container objects (possibly, using a Class built-in method). Then `Invalidate()` the `Panel`, to force the re-paint of its surface. In the Panel's `Paint()` event, repaint all the objects in the List. The same concept applies if your object are UserControls (minus the Paint() event).